# AWS Cloud Front Not caching objects

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cdn

In our origin server we are returning the cache control header with "public,max-age=3600".

We are trying to cache the images returned by our server. The images are served by URL like below

```
https://<>.org/test?obj1="abc"&obj2="def"
```

Where the images returned will be differ by the values sent in the query parameters "obj1" and "obj2".

And then are using default object caching values set in the AWS cloud front. Origin domain has been set as "abc.com".

Only thing we are changing in the Cloud Front setting is to forward the query parameters i.e. we enable "Forward query strings to the origin, and cache based on all parameters in the query string".

In spite of having these settings Cloud Front does not caches at all. Browser based disk caching happens properly due to the header sent.

We fire URL like this `https://d3cudw8d7z9pmo.cloudfront.net/test?obj1="abc"&obj2="def"`

Below are the response headers sent by our server

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=6000
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Count.jpg
Content-Length: 93482
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; sandbox
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Mon, 25 Nov 2019 12:11:21 GMT
Server: xxx
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: possible to paste response headers for a request? Do you have Cache Based on Selected Request Headers set to All ? if no, do you change set new set-cookies in every response ?

Comment: @JamesDean thanks for the response ...i have pasted the response headers...we have not enabled the cache based on selected request headers options

Comment: from what I see d3cudw8d7z9pmo.cloudfront.net --> Is always redirected to  somewhere else doccenter-acf3f8f9f.hana.ondemand.com and CloudFront is actually sending 302 from cache.

Comment: My actual URLs are like this https://doccenter-acf3f8f9f.hana.ondemand.com/mcm/public/v1/open?shr=&obj=...how should i map the domain in my distribution ?..i have just mapped the domain name with https://doccenter-acf3f8f9f.hana.ondemand.com

Comment: Currently CloudFront is not in the picture, doccenter-acf3f8f9f.hana.ondemand.com is pointed directly to Server. you need to do a lot of things like : in DNS doccenter-acf3f8f9f.hana.ondemand.com --> d3cudw8d7z9pmo.cloudfront.net and in CloudFront origin, you need to change the origin domain name to some other value and Whitelist HOST header etc . (careful as it could break things is any misconfiguration)

Comment: @JamesDean thanks again...where do we have to make DNS entry ?...Do you suggest to use CNames ?